# Netsuite User Event Script: Not all user event types firing

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

We have a user event script attached to a sales order in NetSuite, however we are noticing that only the **context.UserEventType.CREATE** is being called. **EDIT**, **COPY** and the others DO NOT catch the sales order manipulations as per spec. Can anyone please verify this. Ive attached a very simple UserEvent script that should throw the context type but it is not working.

This UserEvent script is for a salesorder record:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/record", "N/search"],
    function (record, search) {

        function beforeSubmit(context) {
            throw "beforeSubmit:" + context.type;
        }

        function afterSubmit(context) {
            throw "afterSubmit:" + context.type;
        }

        function beforeLoad(context) {
            throw "beforeLoad:" + context.type;
        }

        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code looks good. Check the deployment and see if the event type is set to create only.